# Unable to print string

Tags: c

How can we replace spaces in a string using pointers? I tried but unable to get it.
While replacing space with hyphen, the control is coming out of the loop without tracing further.

```
while (*str != '\0')
{
    if (*str == ' ') 
    *str = '-'; 
    str++;
 }
 print(str);
```

Comment: Post the code segment so that some one can help you

Comment: While (*str != '\0'){ if(*str == ' ') *str = '-' ; str++;}print(str)

Comment: @user11165861 please don't put code in comments but [edit] your questino instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C programming how to replace spaces in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26932826/c-programming-how-to-replace-spaces-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointers are special type of variables used to store address of other variables. when you changed value inside the str pointer with "str++", it then pointed to the next element and after the while loop str pointed to the last element of the string('\0'). So you must store the the address of the first character of the string to do something with it later.

```
int main() {
    char *s = "abcde", *str =s; // s,str stores address of first character

    while(*str!='\0'){
        if(*str ==' ') 
            *str='-';
        printf("%c", *str);
        str= str+1; // str now points to the next character. But s remains unchanged
    }


   }
```

Comment: You didn't replace anything!

Comment: My bad. Thank you for noticing. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

When you use pointers to do this and increment pointers then `print(str)` will show you end of str so `\0`.

You must store pointer to begin of str:

```
    char* str = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 255);
    memcpy(str, "abc de", 255);
    char* beginStr = str;

    while(*str!='\0') {
        if (*str == ' ') {
            *str = '-';
        }
        str++;
    }

    printf("%s\n", beginStr);
    free(beginStr);
```

Comment: Tried the above code but getting segmentation fault ( core dumped) message

Comment: Right, because when string is declared like this `char* str = "abcde";` this is const. Edited.